# How can I tell why/how two class files are different?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bytecode, decompiling, decompiler

I am trying to recreate some old source.  I have two classes, one from my new source and one from the lost source.  The both classes will decompile to identical source.  However, a bit level compare of the classes still shows differences.  How do tell what causes these differences?

GC_

Comment: Check https://github.com/ingokegel/jclasslib

Comment: There can be many reasons for the binary difference, for example a different class format version comes to mind.

Comment: @Henry I am using the same version of the JDK.

Comment: Don’t put your username at the end of your postings. It is already below your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found just using javap to be very helpful.

I ran this command for both classes:

```
javap -version -l -v -p -c -s -sysinfo ClassName.class > temp.txt
```

Then I compared the two files.  This uncovered the difference I was looking for. It was a line number thing.  I found eclipse's decompiler helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out *what* is different between the two classfiles, I'd recommend using the [Krakatau disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) in `-roundtrip` mode. This will convert the classfiles to a human readable text format that still maps 1:1 to the exact binary encoding of the classfile. Then you can diff the resulting text files to see what is different.

Comment: This may work too, I found I got enough info from javap.  Thanks, though.

Comment: javap can show you common differences in the bytecode, but it won't show you certain differences in the low level encoding.

Comment: I'll let history settle it.  Thanks for the answer, though.